# HttpClient doesn't work on Xamarin iOS release

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I've been struggling for a while now as my iOS Xamarin Release build seems to just hang when I try to to a HTTP Get or Post using the HttpClient. As it seems like there are a lot of people having a lot of different problems, I shared the outcome of my research below and a variety of possible solutions.

Comment: As noted below, I think your answer is being unfairly punished. However, your _question_ could use some work, and risks being closed. Rather than saying "doesn't work" and "seems to just hang", be specific on what problems you encountered, and ideally include some code. And, in the words of the great Alex Trebek, please state it in the form of a question.

Comment: Example code would help illustrate the issue, and would help others with this problem find your (good) answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a couple of things you should look at:

1. Ensure the correct HttpClient is referenced

I found this to be the most common problem. For those using the .net client, you need to make sure that System.Net.Http is explicitly referenced and included in your project.

2. Select the correct HttpClient implementation in the iOS project settings

Around May 2018, new versions of both the SDK and Xamarin platforms were introduced, which added the HttpClient implementation option in the Project Build Options. Be sure to choose the appropriate implementation, based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack) article.

3. Ensure that you are using HTTPS

In the article above you will see that Apple is putting a lot of pressure on developers to make use of secure protocols when doing network connections. All of the HttpGet and HttpPost methods in your code needs to use secure protocols. I found that connections to my http API was blocked and kept hanging on my release builds but everything worked fine when I switched to https. TLS1.2 or higher is also required with these connections.

**IMPORTANT:** I initially did a full find/replace in my project to change my http:// URLs to https://. The problem is that this will also change the URLs for the schemas referenced in the XAML designer files (which causes them to not build). All URLs in the schemas options in the designer files need to stay as generated (using http).

4. Check for thread-blocking issues

When using methods like GetAsync, you might find the method hanging endlessly when using Task.Wait or Task.Result. To prevent this, use this instead:

```
await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

Comment: Why is this an answer? This should be part of your question

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it was part of your research. Still, I feel it would be better as a blog post or something.